# Cannot identify the origin of an error - hypothesis : decimal format conflicts

Tags: debugging, plsql, db2

While executing a DB2 (**V8**) Stored Procedure, I get the following error :

**SQL0304N  A value cannot be assigned to a host variable because the value is 
not within the range of the host variable's data type.  SQLSTATE=22003**

I did not set any kind of tracing or specific error handling and as the error only occurs in our client's validation environment that I'm not allowed to play with, I do not have many options but analyze my code again.

Here is the result of my current analysis. Google is not much of a help...

My "10 pages" procedure creates a CURSOR over a set of data, goes though it and computes values for each element to be inserted it in a table.

I have checked (hopefully) all my variables types versus data types used to fill them and versus the data types of the target table and I do not see any conflict there.

Since there are a lot of decimal numbers, multiplications and additions, my only hypothesis is that a computed value becomes too large for a defined variable. Could anyone confirm that would be the "correct error" ? And would it also apply if the number of digits after the decimal point generated by computing is greater than allowed by the targeted variable type (eg. 100000.123 in decimal(6,2)) ?

I also tried to find a way to debug db2 pl sql through a client but I did not find any solution. If you have any suggestion...

Many thanks in advance for any clue :)

Comment: Depending on the context the SQL is being executed in, that may provide you with the relevant row, which may show you which would be interesting data.  This would be strictly a datatype mismatch - we need to see what you're doing to figure out where.  However, yes, this _could_ be the result of computations you're performing.  Also, cursors are almost never the right choice, when inserting/updating/deleting data (save when needing to batch for transaction size reasons); it may be possible to re-write to a regular `INSERT` statement (which would possibly run faster).

Comment: I have 3 general suggestions. The first is to use some kind of logging. People advocating "to instrument your code" go as far as suggesting, that every other line of code should be an output of what happens or will happen. My second suggestion would be to modularize the "10 pages" procedure. If a piece of code requires scrolling to display all of it, I tend to lose the overview. The third suggestion is to verify your assumptions. When computing stuff, you assume your variables to fulfill whatever criteria. Better make sure beforehand, the values really do. And log the validation results.

Comment: @X-Zero and Juergen Hartelt - Thank you for your comments and help in my investigation !

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself...

First, my last question => I did not find any way to debug db2 pl sql through a client (with DB2 V8 at least).

After I was authorized to work on our integration client's environment, I could confirm my hypothesis was right. The variable format receiving the multiplication was sometimes too small (decimal(10,2)) for the computed result.

The solution adopted was to change the variable format to decimal(15,2) and since the final value to insert still had to be decimal(10,2) upon client's requirements, we validated the following with our client :

1-Check the variable value :

```
if (myval > 9999999,99)
then 
  set myval = 9999999,99;
end if;
```

=> "back to decimal(10,2) requirement"

2-Get back to decimal(10,2) at insert :
This last bit of code also solves the issue when there are too many digits after the decimal point. That was causing an error as well at insert time

```
insert into mytable values (
... ,
CAST(myval AS DECIMAL( 12 , 2 )),
...
)
```